# PHP shorthand/shortcode conditional IF statement: execute code or return message

Tags: php, shortcode

I have a `foreach` loop inside of an if statement. My code is in shorthand format. I do not want the `foreach` loop to execute if the `if` condition returns `true` and instead echo out a message 'sorry database is empty!'

## Functional Code

```
<?php if (!$check == 0) : ?>
    <?php foreach... ?>
       ...
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($check == 0) echo 'Sorry database is empty!'; ?>
```

What I don't like about this code is that I have two separate `if` conditions. Granted it works as it should but I would prefer to to have an `else` in the first `if`.

1. What is the proper syntax for what I want to do?

Alternatively if your answer is something like this:

```
$var_is_greater_than_two = ($var > 2 ? true : false); // returns true
```

Explain how that would stop the `foreach` from executing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use an else:

```
<?php if ($check !== 0) : ?>
    <?php foreach... ?>
       ...
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php else: echo 'Sorry database is empty!'; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

You can also shorten this:

```
$var_is_greater_than_two = ($var > 2 ? true : false); // returns true
```

to just this:

```
$var_is_greater_than_two = ($var > 2); // returns true
```

Comment: Exactly what i needed. Just couldn't get the syntax right and googled it feverishly for 20min with no result. Thank you. How did you know this syntax where did you find it?

Comment: I've been coding PHP for 12 years. Honestly can't remember when or where I learned the specific syntax :)

Comment: Yeah I figured that much -- rephrase the question.. If you needed to look something up.. Where would you look. Besides the PHP manual (which IMHO feel is less than useful)

Comment: I always use php.net as my lookup - or stackoverflow haha. Sorry I'm not much help in the PHP resource area.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add an else to the if ? The code block looks like special rendering, similar to Zenf Framework view script. Unless the special syntax disallows an else, you should be able to do this way.

```
<?php if (!$check == 0) : ?>
   <?php foreach... ?>
   ...
  <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php else :  ?>
      Sorry database is empty!
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

And idea could be to extract the foreach loop to another method. 
Another file or same file have your executeLoop method:

```
<?php 
   function executeLoop()
   {
     foreach(..)
     {
       //do something
     }
  }
?>
enter code here
```

A few lines of code later, you can :

```
<?php (condition)?executeLoop() : echo $something;?>
```

The good thing is you can reuse your code if you wish later.

Comment: How would this work exactly? What would I have to do to the `foreach`

Comment: I'm sorry you misunderstood me. I got your concept, but the question is how would that work in `shortcode` In other words... How would I wrap the `function executeLoop()` in with my current shortcode? And additionally their are multi- `foreach` loops in the block. Would each require `?executeLoop()`